# Can we use SSL/TLS over UDP OR DTLS over TCP IP?

Tags: networking

I am new to networking and I have a doubt on what would happen if we interchange the use of security protocols with their respective transport layer protocols.

Will there be any kind of affect on the delivery performance?

And How is one security protocol different and optimised for specific transport protocol it is designed to be used for?

Answer (score 0):

If you read [DTLS - RFC 6347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347), you will read, that it contains a lot of counter measures for UDP usage. It also explains, why using TLS (with its inherent assumption) will not work for UDP.

If DTLS over TCP would makes sense, depends mostly from your expectations. So why would you like to do that?